# View overlapping for small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using BootStrap grid to design my html pages. Everything is working fine except for small screens. In small screens the views are overlapping like below

[image]

I am using the below code

```html
div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-6   col-sm-offset-1
    col-sm-4   col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
            <div id="poster">
                <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NTI1MTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0OTY0Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4  col-xs-6 col-md-2" >
            <div id="ratingdiv">
                <label>Your Rating</label>
                <div id="rateYo"></div>

                <div class="editbtn">

                    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="deletebtn">
                    <button>Delete</button>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I gave "col-xs-6" but still its not working.
Could some one tell me what I am  doing wrong.

Really appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that you including meta tag?

Comment: Can you include all of your source code instead of html only ?

Comment: can you provide your css too

Comment: Apologies for not including complete source code.As @RidoanSalehNasution mentioned I missed closing tags. Couldn't figure out because this is my first project in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some closing tags. Here you go. Let me know if this is what you've expected.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk2NTI1MTU4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODg0OTY0Nw@@._V1_SX300.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <div id="ratingdiv">
          <div class="row">
            <label>Your Rating</label>
            <div id="rateYo"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Delete</button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I missed closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have provide any css , that's why i got two opinions. first one i think you images overlapping the `col-xs-6`  and the solution is below . may be this will fix your issue

```
#poster { 
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#poster img { 
    width:100%;
}
```

otherwise i think you have set `position:absolute` to `#ratingdiv` , if you set `postion` to `#ratingdiv` just change `position:relative` to the `media queries`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I missed closing tags. It is fixed now.